# Machine Learning terminology to describe when using future data to predict the past values?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, terminology

In time series forcasting, do we have a terminology to describe that, when we randomly shuffle the data and training on future data and predicting the past values? I mean if we destroy the sequential order within the data and build a bad cross validation, what technical term in Machine Learning to describe that behavior?

In Chinese, we often use *time travel*, but I've never seen people use this in English.

Comment: *Backtesting* would apply here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtesting

Comment: @user332577 thank u very much! That's what I'm seeking!

Comment: Backtesting is when you do it *correctly*, i.e. no data leakage in time. The OP asks for the term when you do it in a *wrong* way.

Comment: @MichaelM  I might misunderstood *Backtesting*. Does it mean a correct method, like sklearn's *timeseries cross validation*, to evaluate time series forcasting models?

Comment: Yes, exactly like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In machine learning, people often use the more general term "data leakage".

In mathematical statistics, you could use technical terms like "not adapted to a *filtration*", see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I thought *time travel* is the answer, but no one uses it in English!

Comment: Time travel is nice :-)